# Where to store ExceptionLog in Windpows?

Tags: winforms, logging, permissions, filesystems

**Hi,**

We have a WinForm application running och Windows. This application offers extended logging on the client of Exceptions. Until now we have placed this XML file in the root off the application but Its not always that the correct permissions exists to write in this file.

Is there any best practice for this? Where should the ExceptionLog be placed and how do we handle the permissions?

Maby the log should be placed in a user folder (C:\Users\UserX)

**BestRegards**

Comment: The Windows Event Log ought to be a good place.  Well supported by the EventLog class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use some library for exception logging. For exapmle [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or nlog. They allow you to change the way logs are written. Log4net has big set of different appenders that can log to database, text or xml files, event log and even send email. Log4net could be configured without recompiling your application, according clients machine.

Comment: Thanks! I will look in to that, but is there a preferred place to store the log on a Windows Client?

Comment: I think there is no better place than `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`.